# How does Delayed job work in ruby script

Tags: cron, rubygems, jobs, delayed-job

I want use delayed job on ruby script (not rails) but i can't find anything in delayed `Github` page or wiki page

I want use a background job gems on ruby script like `resque` , `delayed job` , `sidekiq` or etc.

how start background process on ruby script without rails ?